# Can two different developers use the same Admob Ad ID?

Tags: android, admob

I am building an android app for a friend and in return he told me I can have my ads displayed to earn a little bit a money. My question is...can I use my google admob ad ID in another developer account (friend for instance)? Or does my google admob ID only requires to be used with my android developer account?

Update: To clarify - my friend opened his own android developer account so the app will be published through his account not mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AdmobID does not need to match the GooglePlay account under which the app is published.

So yes, you can use your AdmobId in your friends app (as long as he agrees).